# Rider single-click to open file

Tags: c#, rider

I'm trying to setup Rider and I've gone through the settings a couple of times now, and I haven't found any way to change the double-click of opening files in the Explorer-tab to a single-click. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is 'Autoscroll to Source' and locates in the Solution Explorer toolbar, see image:

[image: exmaple]

Comment: It's now "Open Files with Single Click", but in any case it was exactly what I was after, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In version 2023.2.3 it is called "Enable preview tab" under:

File>Settings>Editor>General>Editor Tabs>Opening Policy